# Convergence in measure implies $L^1$ norm-(Vitali Convergence Theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, uniform-integrability

Let $(X, \nu)$ be a finite measure space and let $f_n$ be a sequence
of integrable functions on $X$ converging in measure to a function $f$. Suppose
that $\int |f_n|^p d\nu\leq A$ for some constant $A$ and some $p > 1$. Show that then $f_n \to f$ in the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: $L^{p}$ functions need not be bounded. It is not so easy to apply DCT here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is something related to uniform integrability. The following theorems
and the notion of uniform integrability are due to Vitali, which play
an important role in probability theory. For your problem, solution
follows directly from the following theorems.

Definition: Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty$.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of measurable functions defined on
$X$. We say that $\mathcal{C}$ is uniformly integrable if for each
$\varepsilon>0$, there exists $c>0$ such that 
$$
\int_{\{x\mid|f(x)|\geq c\}}|f|d\mu<\varepsilon
$$
for any $f\in\mathcal{C}$. We remark that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a
finite family of integrable functions, $\mathcal{C}$ is automatically
uniformly integrable.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Proposition 1: Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space with
$\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of measurable functions
defined on $X$. The following are equivalent:

(a) $\mathcal{C}$ is uniformly integrable.

(b) $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}}\|f\|_{1}<\infty$ and for each $\varepsilon>0$,
there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\int_{A}|f|d\mu<\infty$ whenever
$f\in\mathcal{C}$ and $\mu(A)<\delta$.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Theorem 2: Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu(X)<\infty$.
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a family of measurable functions. Let $p\in(1,\infty)$.
If $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}}\|f\|_{p}<\infty$, then $\mathcal{C}$
is uniformly integrable.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Theorem 3 (Vitali): Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space
with $\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of integrable
functions and let $f$ be an integrable function. Then the followings
are equivalent:

(a) $\|f_{n}-f\|_{1}\rightarrow0$.

(b) $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure $\mu$ and the family $\{f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is uniformly integrable.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Proof of Proposition 1:

$(a)\Rightarrow(b):$ Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is uniformly integrable.
Take $\varepsilon=1$, then there exists $c>0$ such that $\int_{[|f|\geq c]}|f|<1$
for all $f\in\mathcal{C}$. Now 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int|f| & = & \int_{[|f|\geq c]}|f|+\int_{[|f|<c]}|f|\\
 & \leq & 1+c\mu(X).
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}}\|f\|_{1}<\infty$. Note for any integrable
function $g$ and $c>0$, we have Markov's inequality: $c\mu\left(\left[|g|\geq c\right]\right)\leq\int_{[|g|\geq c]}|g|\leq\int|g|$.
Let $M=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}}\|f\|_{1}<\infty$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be arbitrary. By uniform integrability of $\mathcal{C}$, there exists
$c>0$ such that $\int_{[|f|\geq c]}|f|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ whenever
$f\in\mathcal{C}$. Let $\delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2c}$. Let $f\in\mathcal{C}$
and $A\in\mathcal{M}$ be arbitrary with $\mu(A)<\delta$. Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{A}|f|\\
 & = & \int_{A\cap[|f|\geq c]}|f|+\int_{A\cap[|f|<c]}|f|\\
 & < & \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+c\mu(A)\\
 & < & \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+c\delta\\
 & = & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}

$(b)\Rightarrow(a):$ Let $M=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}}\|f\|_1<\infty$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $\int_{A}|f|<\varepsilon$
whenever $f\in\mathcal{C}$ and $\mu(A)<\delta$. Let $c=\frac{M+1}{\delta}>0$.
For any $f\in\mathcal{C}$, by Markov's inequality, we have $\mu\left([|f|\geq c]\right)\leq\frac{1}{c}M<\delta$.
It follows that $\int_{[|f|\geq c]}|f|<\varepsilon$.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Proof of Theorem 2:

Let $q\in(1,\infty)$ be such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Let
$M=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}}\|f\|_{p}<\infty$. By Holder inequality,
for any $f\in\mathcal{C}$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int|f| & = & \int|f|\cdot1\\
 & \leq & \|f\|_{p}\|1\|_{q}\\
 & \leq & M\mu(X)^{\frac{1}{q}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{C}}\|f\|_{1}<\infty$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be given. Choose $\delta>0$ such that $M\delta^{\frac{1}{q}}<\varepsilon.$
For any $f\in\mathcal{C}$ and $A\in\mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(A)<\delta$,
by Holder inequality, we have: 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{A}|f|\\
 & \leq & \|f\|_{p}\|1_{A}\|_{q}\\
 & \leq & M\mu(A)^{^{\frac{1}{q}}}\\
 & \leq & M\delta^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
By Proposition 1, it follows that $\mathcal{C}$ is uniformly integrable.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Proof of Theorem 3: $(a)\Rightarrow(b)$: Suppose that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{1}\rightarrow0$.
Let $c>0$. By Markov inequality, we have $\mu\left([|f_{n}-f|\geq c]\right)\leq\frac{1}{c}\|f_{n}-f\|_{1}\rightarrow0$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure
$\mu$. Clearly $\sup_{n}\|f_n-f\|_{1}<\infty$. Let $\varepsilon>0$
be given. For each $n$, choose $\delta_{n}>0$ such that $\int_{A}|f_{n}-f|<\varepsilon$
whenever $\mu(A)<\delta_{n}$. Choose $N$ such that $\|f_{n}-f\|_{1}<\varepsilon$
whenever $n>N$. Define $\delta=\min(\delta_{1},\ldots,\delta_{N})>0$.
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A\in\mathcal{M}$ with $\mu(A)<\delta$.
If $n<N$, we have $\int_{A}|f_{n}-f|<\varepsilon$ because $\mu(A)<\delta\leq\delta_{n}$.
If $n\geq N$, we have $\int_{A}|f_{n}-f|\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{1}<\varepsilon$.
This shows that $\{f_{n}-f\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly integrable
(by Proposition 1). Lastly, since $f$ is integrable and $f_{n}=(f_{n}-f)+f$,
it is easy to see that $\{f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly
integrable.

$(b)\Rightarrow(a):$ Suppose that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure
and that $\{f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly integrable.
Let $g_{n}=f_{n}-f$. Clearly $\{g_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is uniformly
integrable. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, then there exists $\delta>0$
such that $\int_{A}|g_{n}|<\varepsilon/2$ whenver $\mu(A)<\delta$
and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Choose $c>0$ such that $c\mu(X)<\varepsilon/2$.
Since $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ in measure, there exists $N$ such that
$\mu\left([|g_{n}|\geq c]\right)<\delta$ whenever $n\geq N$. For
any $n\geq N$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int|g_{n}|\\
 & = & \int_{[|g_{n}|\geq c]}|g_{n}|+\int_{[|g_{n}|<c]}|g_{n}|\\
 & < & \frac{\varepsilon}{2}+c\mu(X)\\
 & < & \varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
In the above, $\int_{[|g_{n}|\geq c]}|g_{n}|<\varepsilon/2$ because
$\mu\left([|g_{n}|\geq c]\right)<\delta$.

Comment: Nice proof...in the Beggining my first thought was to use uniform integrability,but i  did not know that uniform integrability is used in a whole family of functions..i just knew only the simple theorem for an integrable function...do you have refference for these theorems besides your proof??

Comment: If i proved that $f_n$ is cauchy in the mean then it would be over,but i cannot see something..it cannot be fixed

Comment: @ Marios Gretsas  I learned these stuffs many years ago. It appears in many textbooks about probability theory.

Comment: Probably, I also need to justify that $f$ is integrable.
However, it is easy.
That $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure implies that there exists a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ converging pointwisely a.e. to $f$ (also due to Vitali).
By Fatau's lemma, it is immediate that $f$ is integrable.

Comment: in the definition of uniformly integrable family you take the sets of the form $\{f \geq c\}$..the usual definition mentions sets with measure $<\delta$..is the definition in your answer a special case of the general definition?

Comment: @Marios Gretsas There are two equivalent definitions about uniform integrability. See Proposition 1. Note that, in Proposition 1, the condition that the family is bounded in $L^1$ norm cannot be removed.

Comment: Thank you for answering my comments.... i learned something new today in measure theory...i proved a very much weaker statement than the statement in the post